# AWS SES , Email receiving grayed out

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I have verified my domain in Amazon SES(simple email services) but after verification the Email receiving section grayed out and unable to access .

Comment: What region are you using the SES service in ?

Comment: @bitsapien Canada(Central)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set up your ses domain in a region that allows receiving of emails.
At the moment Canada(Central) is not one. Please see "Email Receiving Endpoints" in:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html